Spring Boot - unable to create Custom Annotation using returnObject
For some reason, Spring Boot's annotation system isn't recognising this.
I wanted to shorten the annotation.
The below works
@GetMapping("/{id}")
@PostAuthorize("@authorizationService.decide(returnObject)")
suspend fun findById(
    @PathVariable id: Long
): ResponseEntity<Student?> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val student = service.findById(id)
        if (student != null) {
            ResponseEntity.ok(student)
        } else {
            ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
        }
    }
}

@Component("authorizationService")
internal class AuthorizationLogic {
    fun decide(response: ResponseEntity<Student?>): Boolean {
        val student = response.body
        return student?.firstname == "Harry"
    }
}

But cannot do
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    @PostAuthorize("@authorizationService.decide(returnObject)")
    annotation class CustomAuthorize

As it cannot recognise returnObject.
Is this possible in Spring Boot, creating annotations of type that are not integers or strings?
